# Sending multiple CuRL requests

Tags: php, curl

Im searching for some help with my CurL code. Im trying to execute multiple URLS but it only runs the last results.

Here is my code:

```
function executeCurl($data) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($data['url']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
unset($data,$url,$ch);

//close connection
}
```

Im running the executeCurl in a loop but it only executes the last result.

Comment: You don't really need the unset statement. Also, somehow I don't think the problem is in this code.

Comment: you are using blocking curl interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `$result` is the problem.
I'm assuming that the $result is defined globally... and that means,

each time you run the `executeCurl()`, the `$result` is being overwritten.
Therefore when your loop is done and you take a look at `$result`, all you have is the result of your LAST `executeCurl()`.

You should return $result, and do whatever you need to do with the result for each loop.

This is a sample code which may help you:

```
// Add a return to your executeCurl function
function executeCurl($data) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($data['url']));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($data,$url,$ch);

    //return the result
    return $result;
}

// Your loop
$results = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($dataList), $i++) { // $dataList is whatever your list of datas are
    $results[$i] = executeCurl($dataList[$i]);
}

// Check out your results
print_r($results);
```

Comment: I think i know what the problem is. The URL i request has Javascript on it. Because its in a while loop the page its executing also executte the javascript twice (or more). Im i right?

Comment: @Kenny The javascript isn't the problem, since Javascripts don't run on a CURL. But if you believe so, try testing your CURL loop with URLs like `http://www.google.com`.  And have you tried out my suggested solution? How was it? (Or was there any part you didn't understand?)

Comment: Yes it worked, but on the executed page there is a javascript onload function that POSTs imgdata to a PHP file with jquery...and there is my problem, cause i can see in chrome debugger that it only does 2 requests instead of 10...But this post helped me, i quess i need to make another one for the javascript problem i got now.

Comment: @Kenny I understand. Yep, the javascript problem would be a different one so good luck on that one too (I can try to help you out there again). Just keep in mind that a CURL won't execute Javascript - it just fetches whatever code is written on the page and returns it to `$result` . Good luck :)

Comment: Well it is working for the last results, it generaties a gooogle charts and saves it into the database, but you cant run the same java 10 times on the same page.